# Cross-origin image loading (twitter profile image)

Tags: javascript, twitter, cors

Javascript newbie here, trying to load Twitter profile images using the URLs returned by the Twitter API. All I can manage to get is the dreaded "Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy." error.

I gather that this is a result of Twitter's lack of support for CORS ([This code](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html) was what I used). If that is the case, how would I get these images without having my server serve as a proxy?

Comment: Wait -- you're trying to use them as WebGL textures? Or just trying to get them into the DOM as normal images?

Comment: Eventually, yes. But since that didn't work, I tried simply loading the image using the crossOrigin property - which didn't work either. Oh, and it did work when the images were from gravatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so to answer my own question - one [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jsmentors/iYICbuWqQps/discussion) is to use JSONP callbacks, which Twitter happens to support. What a hack!

[EDIT] doesn't work for WebGL textures.